# How to import local package to package main

Tags: go

I try to refactor main.go and divide codes to different files.
So I made controller.go as package controller.
But I can't import this local package to main.go.

```
article
  ├ client
  ├ api
  │  ├ main.go
  │  └ contoroller
  │       └ contoroller.go
  ├ nginx
  └ docker-compose.yml
```

```
・client: react/axios
・api: golang/gin
・web-server: nginx
・db: mysql
・container: docker
・ci-tool: travis
・deploy: aws elastic beanstalk
```

main.go

```
package main

import (

"./contoroller"
)

    controller := controller.controller{}

    api := router.Group("/api")
    {
        api.GET("/articles", func(c *gin.Context) {
            controller.getArticleController(c, db)
        })
    }

    router.Run(":2345")
}
```

controller.go

```
package controller

import (
)

func getArticleController(c *gin.Context, db *sql.DB) {
}
```

I expect package controller to be imported.
But the actual is not.

```
undefined: controller
```

Comment: Only exported elements of a package can be accessed after import. Your `controller` is not exported. Nevertheless: You should **NEVER** use local imports. Please read and stick to "How to Write Go Code".

Comment: This is what @Volker is referring to: https://golang.org/doc/code.html

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue by copying `article` to `$GOPATH/src/github.com/[user]/`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the function outside the package You have to rename object. first letter should be capitalized and your code should be next

```
package main

import (

"./contoroller"
)

api := router.Group("/api")
{
    api.GET("/articles", func(c *gin.Context) {
        controller.GetArticleController(c, db)
    })
}

router.Run(":2345")
```

}

controller

```
package controller

import (
)

func GetArticleController(c *gin.Context, db *sql.DB) {
}
```

Comment: Your first example code is invalid, all of that code is illegal outside of a function body.

Comment: This code is just based on your example(there is a lot of typis and invalid using) . O dont think that you use it in real project. It looks like logic proto with error. You should add it to main function.